# How to get phone orientation from Google Maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've tried implementing compass in my app and have used this code as example: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-create-your-own-magnetic-compass-using-androids-internal-sensors/. However, I was also wondering if there is a way to get phone orientation from Google Maps API or maybe some other API in existance? I've searched Google but found nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple orientation check (portrait vs. landscape) won't be sufficient. You'll need to check the rotation of the screen from it's "natural" orientation, and adjust your compass heading calculation accordingly.

```
((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()
```

See: [Display.getRotation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation())

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it was not totally clear if you are trying to implement a compass **view** of some sort, or just get the general data on the orientation on the phone.

According to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD0), there is a `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` value which can be used to determine magnetic values.  If you scroll down on that page, you will also see other variables useful for orientation, including the deprecated `TYPE_ORIENTATION`.  The new way to handle orientation is

```
float[] getOrientation (float[] R, 
                float[] values)
```

And in case you didn't find it above, the function to use for magnetic field is

```
GeomagneticField (float gdLatitudeDeg, 
                float gdLongitudeDeg, 
                float altitudeMeters, 
                long timeMillis)
```

And the documentation can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.html).  You may end up having to go down the rabbit hole of **quaternions** if you want hyper-accurate and useful total dead reckoning and orientation data.  If you do go that route, I recommend the docs from the [Unity Game Engine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html), as they do a good job explaining the consequences and meaning of quaternions without having to necessarily dive all the way into the math.

Comment: I need data about orientation of phone. I've already implemented magnetic field sensor, but didn't implement any filters yet so I was wondering if there was already an API out there which would come packaged with everything required to implement compass with high precision without writing it all myself.

Comment: There's no API that I know of that will take care of use cases like that for you. If you want to maintain heading regardless of how the user changes device orientation, you need to check for rotation specifically and apply the calculation yourself, as I stated in my answer.